# Priority Queue Declaration C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, priority-queue

I have been rather frustrated at this for awhile and i just can't seem to find where error is (note my compiler does not support c++11)

basically i am trying to construct a priority Queue where each element contains two further elements. The first element being a queue of char vectors and the second being a heuristic to evaluate this queue.

The contents of the queue of char vectors are not important just the evaluation of the heuristic (greater) as follows

```
struct pathP
{
public:
    queue<vector<char>> que;
    int hue;
};

struct pathComp
{
    bool comp(const pathP &s1, const pathP &s2) const
    {
        return s1.hue < s2.hue;
    }
};
```

----------------------- (in a function elsewhere in my code)

```
priority_queue<pathP, vector<pathP>, pathComp> endV;
queue<vector<char>> saveQ;
pathP pathStore;
int h1, heur;
```

----------------------- (further down the function)

```
pathStore.que = saveQ;
heur = h1;
pathStore.hue = heur;
endV.push(pathStore); //error C2064
```

error c2064 reads "term does not evaluate to a function taking 2 arguments"
and i am not sure how to fix it

Comment: Can you post a [mcve]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
struct pathComp
{
    bool operator()(const pathP &s1, const pathP &s2) const
    {
        return s1.hue < s2.hue;
    }
};
```

`priority_queue` doesn't use a method called `comp`. Instead you should define a *functor* which is a class which overrides `operator()` as above.